# Foreign key error "RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference" in join statement. Linq with MVC3

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

This is a part of my database:

[image: Tables relationships]

I'm trying to get all groups that study a subject which is assigned to a specific exam:

```
ExamView.GrpLst = (from ex in en.Exam
                                   join instSub in en.Instructor_Subject on ex.Instructor_Subject_ID equals instSub.ID
                                   join sub in en.Subject on instSub.SubjectID equals sub.ID
                                   join trkSub in en.Track_Subject on sub.ID equals trkSub.SubjectID
                                   join trk in en.Track on trkSub.TrackID equals trk.ID
                                   join grp in en.Group.Include("Track") on trk.ID equals grp.TrackID
                                   where ex.ID == id select grp).ToList();
```

In my view I display results as following:

```
 @foreach (var g in Model.GrpLst)
{ 
    <tr>
        <td>@g.GroupName</td>
    </tr>
}
```

It works and get the results with no problem.

The problem starts when trying in my view to display the track that is assigned to this group:

```
 @foreach (var g in Model.GrpLst)
{ 
    <tr>
        <td>@g.GroupName</td>
        <td>@g.Track.TrackName</td>
    </tr>
}
```

I get this exception message:

```
return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<Track>("ExaminationModel.FK_Groups_Track", "Track").Value;
```

I tried to include the "Track" table to the group in the linq statement, but in vain.

I appreciate any suggestions.